# accessing a different schema across database link

Tags: sql, database, oracle, hyperlink

I have access to a schema (my_schema) on a read-only database, and on that database there's another schema that contains the data I need.  I can connect directly to my_schema and query other_schema.table_name without a problem.

I have another database on another_server and I would like to access other_schema.table_name via a database link.

I can create a dblink (db_link) from my local DB (another_server) to my_schema, but I don't know how to refer to objects in other_schema if it's even possible.

Ideally I could create a view in my_schema that hides the owner of the table:  create view table_name_v as select * from other_schema.table_name.  Unfortunately, the DBA tells me it's a read-only database and they can't create views or even synonyms over there.

Is it at all possible for me to access the other_schema.table_name across the DB link?  Something like this:

```
sqlplus> select * from other_schema.table_name@db_link;
```

Comment: Have you tried your select statement?  That should be exactly the syntax you should use assuming you have access to that schema and table

Comment: Not sure what happened.  First time I tried I got an error.  Saw this comment and tried it again:  works like a charm.  ?!?  Thanks!

Comment: Some of the operations Oracle does are asynchronous and thus take a while to propagate.  It's possible the link hadn't been created when you tested it